# How to convert Vec of values into slices of references

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have

```
struct Data {
    // details omitted
}

fn parse_data(raw: &str) -> Option<Data> {
    // details omitted
}

fn step1(datas: &[&Data]) {
    // details omitted
}

fn step2(datas: &[&Data]) {
    // details omitted
}
```

I want a function that takes a collection of the raw data type (in my example `&str`), converts them and the passes borrows of the data into `step1` and `step2`.

```
fn do_things(raw_strs: &[&str]) {
   // notice this Vec owns all the Data items
   let datas: Vec<Data> = raw_strs.iter()
      .flat_map(|r| parse_data(r))
      .collect();

   // this eludes me on how to call these
   step1(datas.as_slice());
   step2(datas.as_slice());
}
```

I get "expected `&Data`, found struct `Data`".

How can I create a slice of references so I can pass the data to multiple functions, without creating copies of the `Data`?

Comment: Is it not possible to accept iterators into your step functions, rather than slices?

Comment: @eggyal i'm open to that as well, if there is a hint as to what type to use

Comment: For iterator just use `impl IntoIterator<Item = &Data>`?  Then call with `&datas`?  Or else accept `&[impl Borrow<Data>]`?

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3fbc5a53a67a75680da0f14a4a8fee1).

Comment: Or perhaps the step functions can just accept `&[Data]` (it isn't clear in your question why not?).

Comment: I would say he is missundersntanding `&[T]` and `&[&T]`, usually just `&[T]` is enough if you come from some owning `[T]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create another `Vec<&Data>` and pass a slice to the methods:

```rust
fn do_things() {
   // notice this Vec owns all the Data items
   let datas: Vec<Data> = (0..10)
      .map(|r| Data {})
      .collect();

    let data_refs = datas.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
   // this eludes me on how to call these
   step1(&data_refs);
   step2(&data_refs);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35e9705738dc62ef66277218116b0ea4)

**But**, unless you already have working structures with `[&Data]`, your methods should take just `&[Data]`, there is no moving involving, you are just referencing your `Vec` as an slice.

> How can I create a slice of references so I can pass the data to multiple functions, without creating copies of the Data?

As said, when using `&[Data]` you are not copying them, you just pass a reference to a slice of `Data`. Not moving or copying involved in the `Data` themselves.